# Extract dates from filename

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a situation where I need to extract dates from the file names whose general pattern is `[filename_]YYYYMMDD[.fileExtension]`

e.g. **"xxx_20100326.xls"**  or **x2v_20100326.csv**

The below program does the work

```
//Number of charecter in the substring is set to 8 
//since the length of YYYYMMDD is 8

public static string ExtractDatesFromFileNames(string fileName)
{

    return fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("_") + 1, 8);
}
```

Is there any better option of achieving the same?

I am basically looking for standard practice.

I am using C#3.0 and dotnet framework 3.5

Edit:

I have like the solution and the way of answerig of LC. I have used his program like

```
string regExPattern = "^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:\\..*)?$";
string result =  Regex.Match(fileName, @regExPattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

The input to the function is : **"x2v_20100326.csv"**

But the output is: **2010** instead of `20100326`(which is the expected one).

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Your current approach (using `IndexOf`) will fail if the file have multiple underscores. Rather use `LastIndexOf`. Even if at the moment you know there will be only one underscore, it is a small change to avoid some future debugging sessions in the event that it does change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex, *especially if it's possible there's more than one underscore in the filename*. Then you can capture the year, month, day and return a `DateTime` if necessary. This way you can make sure you're extracting the right portion of the filename and it indeed matches the pattern you're searching for.

For the pattern `[filename_]YYYYMMDD[.fileExtension]`, I'm thinking something like:

```
^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:\..*)?$
```

Then your captured groups will be year, month, and day, in that order.

**Explanation:**

`^`: The beginning of your string.

`(?:.*_)?`: An optional non-capturing group, containing any number of characters followed by an underscore.

`([0-9]{4})`: A capturing group containing exactly four digits.

`([0-9]{2})`: A capturing group containing exactly two digits.

`(?:\..*)?`: An optional non-capturing group, containing a dot followed by any number of characters.

`$`: The end of your string.

However, I will add that if you're sure your filenames have one and only one underscore, and the date follows that underscore, the code you have is cleaner and will probably be slightly faster than the regex. It's something to keep in mind based on the expected input set.

Comment: Sir, I have used your program like

string regExPattern = "^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})(?:\\..*)?$";
            string result =  Regex.Match(fileName, @regExPattern).Groups[1].Value;

and the input being "x2v_20100326.csv". I am getting teh output as 2010. Please help

Comment: @Newbie, He split his groups into 3. One for the year, one for the month, and one for the day. Go for groups 2 and 3. If you don't care about splitting the date up into its various parts, perhaps modify the regex to `^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{8})(?:\..*)?$`

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is sufficient as long as you are sure of the input being that standard format. If there's a chance it won't be then you should add some error handling for scenarios where there is no underscore, or the days/months aren't represented by 2 digits (which will mess up the 8 character substring count), followed by a [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) to ensure it's a real date.

Your other options are:

- **Regex**: overkill for such a well-defined pattern.
- **LINQ**: using the `SkipWhile`, `Skip`, `TakeWhile` methods to ignore the underscore and capture the numbers until the period is encountered. This query ends up looking confusing and the result needs to be transformed to a string.
- **String.Split**: split on `{ '_', '.' }` and use the array element representing the date.

None of these options are going to yield code that looks clearer than what you already have and performance probably won't be any better.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've got is fine, except that you may want to check the return value of `IndexOf` in case you encounter a file with no _, ie.

```
 int index = fileName.IndexOf("_");
 if (index != -1)
     return fileName.Substring(index + 1, 8);
 else
     ...
```

If you want to check whether it's a valid date you can then call `DateTime.TryParseExact`