# Parsing a filename and get date

Tags: c#

Looking for a way to parse a date from a filename.The way the filename is named has no convention but can contain a date within the string.How can I extract the date from this filename?

```
20151030Thisisafilename

Thisisafilename20151030

Thisisafilename2015-10-30
```

many thanks

EDIT
my question is different because I dont have delimeters eg "_"

Comment: Your string has _always_ only addional `Thisisafilename` string beside your `DateTime`? Are those only formats? `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions? Looks like the right approach. https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222693/get-date-from-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917203/finding-if-a-string-contains-a-date-and-time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381997/finding-datetime-from-a-string-c-sharp

Comment: Any info on zero based months, eg. 2015-1-2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract dates from filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042331/extract-dates-from-filename)

Comment: regular expression is the correct approach but I dont know it

Comment: Ah, perfect time to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should fit:

```
\d{4}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}
```

It looks for a sequence of 8 digits, optionally separated by two dashes.

It works for the following formats:

- 20151231
- 2015-12-31
- 201512-31
- 2015-1231

If you want a 'all or nothing approach', this should work:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{8})
```

That works for:

- 20151231
- 2015-12-31